# Video background not visible on mobile devices

Tags: css, html, video, mobile, html5-video

I wanted to know what is the reason that if the PC version with the video background is displayed, but not visible on mobile devices. HELP ME! Please!

```
<video id="videobcg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0" >
    <source src="landing-resources/landing/video/video_full_screen.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="landing-resources/landing/video/videofullscreen.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="landing-resources/landing/video/videofullscreen.mp4" type="video/mp4">     
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most phones and tablets by default do not play video automatically, you will need to add a static background as a fallback for mobile devices.

https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/